# Is Vishnu avatar of Krishna or krishna avatar of vishnu?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, vaishnav

You know in general perspective it was always vishnu taking avatar as Krishna
but if you go in depth and listen to the devotees of iskon they seem to say the reverse infact they even go a step ahead and say usualy vishnu takes avatar as krishna but this time the god version came himself through vishnu.

Comment: Can you link such a statement so that we can see what exactly they are saying and what their 'logic' is?

Answer (score 1):

In most texts, Krishna is avatar of Vishnu. Only in Brahmavaivarta Purana, garga Samhita etc is Krishna superior to Vishnu.

Garga Samhita says -

> "Śrī Nārada said: As everyone looked on, Lord Hari, the eight-armed
> master of Vaikuṇṭha, appeared and merged in the the body of Lord
> Kṛṣṇa. The perfect, ferocious, and powerful Lord Nrsiṃha, who was
> effulgent as millions of suns, merged in Lord Kṛṣṇa's effulgence. Then
> the master of Śvetadvīpa, who was decorated with a thousand arms, came
> in a splendid chariot drawn by a hundred thousand horses. Opulent with
> many weapons, accompanied by the goddess of fortune, and served by
> many associates, He suddenly merged in the body of Śrī Kṛṣṇa. Then,
> holding a bow and arrows, glorious with Sītā, and accompanied by His
> brothers, lotus-eyed Lord Rāmacandra came in a golden chariot that was
> effulgent as a hundred million suns, (decorated) with swaying cāmaras,
> opulent with countless monkey-kings, rumbling with ten thousand
> wheels, (decorated with) ten thousand flags, and (pulled by) ten
> thousand horses, and merged in the body of Lord Kṛṣṇa. Then Lord
> Yajña, who is known as Nārāyaṇa and Hari, who is glorious like a flame
> in the fire of cosmic devastation, who is the master of the demigods,
> and who is glorious with His consort Dakṣiṇa, came in a splendid and
> beautiful chariot and suiddenly merged in the dark form of Lord Kṛṣṇa.
> Then Lord Nara-Nārāyaṇa, whose eyes were large, who had four arms, who
> was dressed as a sage, who was splendid like a dark cloud, whose
> matted hair was a lightning flash, who observed an unbroken vow (of
> celibacy), and who was surrounded by splendid multitudes of the kings
> of sages, suddenly merged in the handsome dark form of Lord Kṛṣṇa as
> everyone looked on, their hearts filled with wonder. Filled with
> wonder, and now understanding that Śrī Kṛṣṇa is the original Supreme
> Personality of Godhead, the demigods offered many prayers."

Here, Garga Samhita portrays Krishna as the source of everything. Vishnu, Nara-narayana, Rama, Narasimha etc all merge into Krishna's body.

Answer (score 0):

According to Shiva Purana, it's Lord Vishnu only who takes the form of Krishna in Goloka. Again, this Krishna of Goloka takes all the incarnations.

Sri Shiva Purana 2.2:2:25.:

> Rāma said:—
>
> 1-2. **O Goddess, formerly once, Śiva, the creator supreme, called Viśvakarman to His highest region. He made him erect a large hall of great beauty in His cowshed, and an exquisite throne there.**
>
> 3. **Śiva, caused Viśvakarman to make an excellent, divine, wonderful umbrella for warding off obstacles.**
>
> .
>
> 10. With a delightful mind He called Viṣṇu from Vaikuṇṭha. O Goddess, Śiva rejoiced at the perfect devotion of Viṣṇu.
> 11. In an auspicious hour, the great lord made Viṣṇu sit on the exquisite throne and delightedly decorated him in every way.
> 12. A beautiful coronet was fixed on Viṣṇu and the auspicious holy thread was tied to his waist. He was then coronated by lord Śiva in the Cosmic Hall.
> 13. What was His own and even non-transferable, Śiva the independent and favourably disposed to His devotees, conferred on Viṣṇu and eulogised him.
> 14. The lord who is favourably disposed to His devotees, revealing Himself independent but subservient to the boons granted by Him, spoke these words to Brahmā the creator of all worlds.
>
> Lord Śiva said:—
>
> 15-16. **Lord, may you all hear. From now onwards, at my bidding, this Viṣṇu has become worthy of my respect and that of all devas. Dear one, you too bow to him. May all the Vedas extol him at my bidding as they extol me.**
>
> .
>
> Lord Śiva said:—
>
> 20. At my bidding you are now the creator, sustainer and destroyer of all the worlds. You are the bestower of virtue, wealth and love and the chastiser of people of evil predilection.
> 21. **You are the lord of the universe. You are worthy of the worship of the universe. You will be invincible in battle anywhere even against me (Same boon given to Sage Narayana). You will be endowed with great strength and valour.**
> 22. You take three Śaktis—will etc. conferred by me. You can have the power of exhibiting diverse sports and independence in the three worlds.
> 23. O Viṣṇu, persons who hate you shall indeed be chastised and curbed by me with strenuous efforts. Salvation shall be given by me, O Viṣṇu, to your devotees.
> 24. Accept this Māyā too which cannot be withstood by devas and others and by which the entire universe will be deluded and made insentient as it were.
>
> .
>
> 27. **While stationed here you protect the entire universe taking different incarnations and diverse ways of protection.**
> 28. **This place of great prosperity and glory in my own world shall be famous as Goloka. It will be very brilliant.**
> 29. O Viṣṇu, I shall certainly see the various incarnations of yours on the earth and shall be delighted by your devotion to me.
>
> Rāma said:—
>
> 30. After conferring thus unlimited prosperity on Viṣṇu, Śiva, the consort of Śivā, freely sported about at Kailāsa along with His attendants.
> 31. **Thenceforth lord of Lakṣmī assumed the guise of a cowherd. The lord of cowherds (Krishna), cowherdesses and the cows wandered there with pleasure.**
> 32. **The delightful Viṣṇu protected the universe taking up various incarnations and sustaining it at the bidding of Siva.**
> 33. **Now He has taken a fourfold incarnation at the bidding of Śiva. I who am Rāma, and my brothers Bharata, Lakṣmaṇa and Śatrughna are His incarnations.**

Again,

Sri Shiva Maha Purana 2.5:5:31.:

> Śiva said:—
>
> 4. **At my bidding Viṣṇu has assumed the form of Kṛṣṇa and is stationed in the cowshed in the beautiful Goloka presided over by me.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..